# System of equations with inequality

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations, determinant

> **Question Statement:-**
>
> If $$\begin{eqnarray}
> x=cy+bz\\
> y=az+cx\\
> z=bx+ay
> \end{eqnarray}$$ where $x,y,z$ are not all zero, prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc=1$
>
> Further if at least one of $a,b,c$ is a proper fraction, prove that:-
>
> (i) $a^2+b^2+c^2\lt 3$
>
> (ii) $abc\gt-1$

---

**Attempt at a solution:-**

The first part (i.e the part where we have to prove $a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc=1$) of the question gets completed pretty easily.

As the given system of equations is homogeneous and as $x,y,z$ are not all zero so the solutions are non-trivial. And for a homogeneous system of equations to have non-trivial solutions we have :-

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & -c & -b\\
-c & 1 & -a\\
-b & -a & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

And on expanding the determinant we get
$(1-a^2)+c(-c-ab)-b(ac+b)=0\implies a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc=1$

I am not able to come up with any way to solve the remaining two portions of the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $a$ is a proper fraction, then

$$a^2<1$$

Considering quadratic in $c$,

$$c^2+2abc+a^2+b^2-1=0$$

Admitting real value of $c$,

\begin{align*}
  \Delta & \ge 0 \\
  4(a^2-1)(b^2-1) &\ge 0 \\
  b^2-1 & \le 0
\end{align*}

Hence,
$$b^2 \le 1$$

Similarly,
$$c^2 \le 1$$

Hence,

> $$a^2+b^2+c^2<3$$

Also

> $$abc=\frac{1-a^2-b^2-c^2}{2}>-1$$